# How to get GCC-style line annotated error messages from Python interpreter?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, gcc

When I compile a program using GCC and there is a part of the line that is incorrect, the error message I receive usually annotates the incorrect part. For example, an invalid header file leads to

```
prog.cpp:1:10: fatal error: iostreamm: No such file or directory
 #include <iostreamm>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Notice the `^` above that tells exactly where in the statement the error is. When I run a Python script that does a nontrivial task, a similar `^` does not appear, but I believe there is enough information for the interpreter to output one. Is there way I could view nicer `^` annotated error messages from the Python interpreter?

Example Python error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hw1/code/assignment.py", line 255, in <module>
    main()
  File "hw1/code/assignment.py", line 245, in main
    train(my_model, train_inputs, train_labels)
  File "hw1/code/assignment.py", line 157, in train
    grad_w, grad_b = model.back_propagation(train_inputs[i], probs, train_labels[i])
  File "hw1/code/assignment.py", line 96, in back_propagation
    grad_w[j, k] += self.learning_rate * (y_j - probs[j, i]) * inputs[i, k]
IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 10
```

Wanted Python error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hw1/code/assignment.py", line 255, in <module>
    main()
  File "hw1/code/assignment.py", line 245, in main
    train(my_model, train_inputs, train_labels)
  File "hw1/code/assignment.py", line 157, in train
    grad_w, grad_b = model.back_propagation(train_inputs[i], probs, train_labels[i])
  File "hw1/code/assignment.py", line 96, in back_propagation
    grad_w[j, k] += self.learning_rate * (y_j - probs[j, i]) * inputs[i, k]
                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 10
```

Comment: In your example, how would the error handler know that the problem is related to the first index, as opposed to the second, or the variable name, or a missing function etc?

Comment: Maybe there is a way to pass that information to the point where the IndexError is caught? I'm not sure of the details of how the Python interpreter works, but I imagine this shouldn't be harder than keeping track of what `(line_number, char_number)` is currently being interpreted.

Comment: In your C++ example, the compiler exactly knows the execution point. In Python, the error could be thrown from anywhere (libraries etc). There is no way for the library to know what the source code looks like and also no way for the error handler to connect an arbitrary error to an expression.

Comment: `How to get GCC-style line annotated error messages from Python interpreter?` Patch python interpreter to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do get such arrows for [syntax errors](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html), which is the closest equivalent to a compilation error for the Python implementation.

What you are asking for is arrows pointing to the sub-expressions that lead to `raise` (`throw` in C++). Neither GCC nor CPython *at the moment* do that.